# Data does not print into the file, resulting in a empty file

Tags: python, file, is-empty

I've been trying to have this data write to the "scenario_out.txt" file. However, when I run the code I do not any get errors but my text file does come out to empty, so no data was ever put into the file. . I'm reviewing my notes but I don't see where I went wrong.

```
 # Display results of scenario
    def file_save_flow(save_to_file,          # save to a file object if save_to_file = True
                       file_object,           # name of file object to save to
                       scen_year,
                       age,
                       s_bal,
                       bal_pv,
                       inv_gains,
                       ann_savings,
                       ss_payment,
                       major_inc,
                       major_exp,
                       tax_rate,
                       tar_ret_spend,
                       net_ret_spend,
                       ret_pre_tax_spend,
                       taxes,
                       end_bal
                       ):
        """ file_save_flow() test output
            >>> out_file = open("scenario_out.txt","w")
            >>> file_save_flow(save_to_file      = True,
            ...             file_object       = out_file,
            ...             scen_year         = 0,
            ...             age               = 60,
            ...             s_bal             = 100000,
            ...             bal_pv            = 100000,
            ...             inv_gains         = 1000,
            ...             ann_savings       = 1000,
            ...             ss_payment        = 1000,
            ...             major_inc         = 1000,
            ...             major_exp         = 1000,
            ...             tax_rate          = 0.15,
            ...             tar_ret_spend     = 50000,
            ...             net_ret_spend     = 40000,
            ...             ret_pre_tax_spend = 60000,
            ...             taxes             = 10000,
            ...             end_bal           = 120000
            ...             )
            >>> out_file.close()
            >>> in_file = open("scenario_out.txt","r")
            >>> print(in_file.read())
            Year             :0
            Age              :60
            Start Bal        :100,000.00
            Start Bal PV     :100,000.00
            Invest Gains     :1,000.00
            Ann Savings      :1,000.00
            SS Payment       :1,000.00
            Major Inc        :1,000.00
            Major Exp        :1,000.00
            Tax Rate         :15.00%
            Targ Ret Spend   :50,000.00
            Net Ret Spend    :40,000.00
            Ret Pre-tax Spend:60,000.00
            Taxes            :10,000.00
            End Bal          :120,000.00
            <BLANKLINE>
            >>> in_file.close()
        
        """
    
        #=============================My Code================================
        if save_to_file == True:
            print(' Year              :'  , scen_year, 
              '\n Age               :',age,
              '\n Start Bal         :', (format(s_bal, ',.2f')) ,
              '\n Start Bal PV      :', (format(bal_pv, ',.2f')), 
              '\n Invest Gains      :', (format(inv_gains, ',.2f')),
              '\n Ann Savings       :', (format(ann_savings,',.2f')),
              '\n SS Payment        :', (format(ss_payment, ',.2f')),
              '\n Major Inc         :', (format(major_inc, ',.2f')),
              '\n Major Exp         :', (format(major_exp, ',.2f')),
              '\n Tax Rate          :', (format(tax_rate, '.2%')), 
              '\n Targ Ret Spend    :', (format(tar_ret_spend, ',.2f')),
              '\n Net Ret Spend     :', (format(net_ret_spend, ',.2f')),
              '\n Ret Pre-tax Spend :', (format(ret_pre_tax_spend, ',.2f')), 
              '\n Taxes             :', (format(taxes, ',.2f')), 
              '\n End Bal           :', (format(end_bal, ',.2f')))
      #============================================================================      
            
            
    
    # test function
    out_file = open("scenario_out.txt","w")    # set up the file object to write to
    file_save_flow(save_to_file      = True,
                   file_object       = out_file,
                   scen_year         = 0,
                   age               = 60,
                   s_bal             = 100000,
                   bal_pv            = 100000,
                   inv_gains         = 1000,
                   ann_savings       = 1000,
                   ss_payment        = 1000,
                   major_inc         = 1000,
                   major_exp         = 1000,
                   tax_rate          = 0.15,
                   tar_ret_spend     = 50000,
                   net_ret_spend     = 40000,
                   ret_pre_tax_spend = 60000,
                   taxes             = 10000,
                   end_bal           = 120000
                   )
    out_file.close()
    in_file = open("scenario_out.txt","r")     # read back the contents saved to the file
    print(in_file.read())
    in_file.close()
```

I've tied some bool variable to use as a flag , but still no luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the moment, you're just printing your output to the console, rather than actually saving it to the file.

You probably want something like

```py
if save_to_file == True:
    output = (
          ' Year              : ' + str(scen_year) + 
        '\n Age               : ' + str(age) + 
        '\n Start Bal         : ' + (format(s_bal, ',.2f')) + 
        '\n Start Bal PV      : ' + (format(bal_pv, ',.2f')) + 
        '\n Invest Gains      : ' + (format(inv_gains, ',.2f')) + 
        '\n Ann Savings       : ' + (format(ann_savings,',.2f')) + 
        '\n SS Payment        : ' + (format(ss_payment, ',.2f')) + 
        '\n Major Inc         : ' + (format(major_inc, ',.2f')) + 
        '\n Major Exp         : ' + (format(major_exp, ',.2f')) + 
        '\n Tax Rate          : ' + (format(tax_rate, '.2%')) + 
        '\n Targ Ret Spend    : ' + (format(tar_ret_spend, ',.2f')) + 
        '\n Net Ret Spend     : ' + (format(net_ret_spend, ',.2f')) + 
        '\n Ret Pre-tax Spend : ' + (format(ret_pre_tax_spend, ',.2f')) + 
        '\n Taxes             : ' + (format(taxes, ',.2f')) + 
        '\n End Bal           : ' + (format(end_bal, ',.2f'))
    )
    file_object.write(output)
```

This creates a big string of your output data, then writes it to your file object.

Comment: so i have a question. When i run into a similar situation instead of using print, i should use the "output"?

Comment: I wouldn't quite phrase it that way. I'd say that when you want to write to a file, instead of using `print`, use `f.write` where f is the file object. `f.write` takes in data differently than print though. It expects a string, rather than a series of comma separated values, so you'll have to format your output before writing it to your file

Comment: You could also use @Grismar's approach and print "to a file". Their solution with `print('abc', file=file_object)` works just as well

Answer (score 0):

If you remove all the fluff, your code looks exactly like this:

```
def file_save_flow(save_to_file, file_object, data):
    if save_to_file == True:
        print('Data: ', data)

out_file = open("scenario_out.txt", "w")
file_save_flow(save_to_file=True, file_object=out_file, data='data')
out_file.close()
in_file = open("scenario_out.txt", "r")
print(in_file.read())
in_file.close()
```

From that, it's immediately clear that your function does only one thing: it prints something if `save_to_file` is `True` and it prints nothing otherwise. It doesn't do anything with `file_object`.

So, although you create and open a file and pass the file handle to your function, you don't actually use it in the `print()` statement.

This would work:

```
def file_save_flow(save_to_file, file_object, data):
    if save_to_file == True:
        print('Data: ', data, file=file_object)
    else:
        print('Data: ', data)
```

Or, to avoiding repeating yourself:

```
def file_save_flow(save_to_file, file_object, data):
    print('Data: ', data, file=file_object if save_to_file else None)
```

Comment: Some of that fluff is my professor input. That's what he uses to grade us, make sure the format is correct when he runs his tests, we're not allowed to remove that. The little block where it says, "My code" is what I wrote so I can get the the proper output, but its coming out blank in the file.

Comment: And if you read what I wrote, you can tell what needs to change in your code - I just removed the fluff to focus on what needs to change.

Comment: Ohhhh okay, sorry im still new to this. Still trying to comprehend this language .

Comment: That's OK, stick with it - it takes time and it's not easy, but you'll have a super power if you master it. As for asking questions on StackOverflow, you'll get the best results if you try to boil your question down to just the parts you really don't get - making people do the work for you (either writing the code, or having to read and then ignore a lot of stuff that doesn't really matter) tends to go poorly.  Keep asking questions though, no such thing as a stupid question.